# Does ASP.net Report Viewer / Reports require Reporting Services on SQL server

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I have an application that makes use of Report Viewer and Report (.rdlc) files. Does this mean that I need to have "Reporting Services" installed on my SQL server??

Also would not having "SQL Server Analysis services" affect me any way
I want to make sure I keep using

```
 - SQL Server Profiler
 - SQL Server Agent - create and run management tasks
 - Reporting services if the first question's answer is true.
```

Comment: This link may help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa237366%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no, you don't need Reporting Services installed or running for the ReportViewer control to render a report locally.

You just need to make sure you have the [Report Viewer redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?familyid=CC96C246-61E5-4D9E-BB5F-416D75A1B9EF&displaylang=en) installed on the server that is going to be hosting the application that uses the ReportViewer control.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the ReportViewer in local mode (which it sounds like you are as you are using RDLC files instead of RDL), then no, you don't need Reporting Servics at all. If you want more power, then you can install Reporting Services, deploy your reports there, put ReportViewer in server mode and have it pull the reports off the server.